# Vector potential $ \vec A$ of two parallel conductors

Tags: electromagnetism

Let's say we have two parallel conductors of length $l$ parallel to the x-axis at $y=y_0$ and $y=-y_0$.

Let's say the upper conductor has the current density $j$ and the lower one $-j$.

Now I want to calculate the vector potential $\vec A$ of this arrangement by superposition: 
$ \vec A = \vec A_1 + \vec A_2 $

Using $ \Delta \vec A = - \mu_0 \vec j $ I get:

$\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x^2} A_x = -\mu j_x \,\, $  for one current.

How do I proceed now? I know I can take the integral to get $A_x$, but which bounds do I have to put in?

Comment: $\Delta \vec A = - \mu_0 \vec j$ does not imply: 

$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} A_x = -\mu j_x$. You have $\Delta A_x = - \mu_0 j_x$

Comment: What FrodCube means is that you match the $x$ component of $\nabla^2\mathbf A$ to $j_x$.